# Using ProGuard causing unsuccessful build or force close with empty UI after trying some ProGuard rules

Tags: java, android, proguard, android-proguard

I am using ProGuard and shrink resources features in my app, as shown below:

```
buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled true
            shrinkResources true
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
```

When I build the app, it shows some warnings, with unsuccessful build, as shown below:

```
Information:Gradle tasks [:app:assembleRelease]
Warning:org.apache.harmony.awt.datatransfer.DataProxy: can't find superclass or interface java.awt.datatransfer.Transferable
Warning:org.apache.harmony.awt.datatransfer.NativeClipboard: can't find superclass or interface java.awt.datatransfer.Clipboard
Warning:com.sun.mail.imap.protocol.IMAPSaslAuthenticator: can't find referenced class javax.security.sasl.Sasl
Warning:com.sun.mail.imap.protocol.IMAPSaslAuthenticator: can't find referenced class javax.security.sasl.SaslClient
Warning:com.sun.mail.imap.protocol.IMAPSaslAuthenticator: can't find referenced class javax.security.sasl.SaslException
Warning:com.sun.mail.imap.protocol.IMAPSaslAuthenticator: can't find referenced class javax.security.sasl.SaslClient
Warning:com.sun.mail.imap.protocol.IMAPSaslAuthenticator: can't find referenced class javax.security.sasl.SaslException
Warning:com.sun.mail.imap.protocol.IMAPSaslAuthenticator$1: can't find referenced class javax.security.auth.callback.NameCallback
Warning:com.sun.mail.imap.protocol.IMAPSaslAuthenticator$1: can't find referenced class javax.security.sasl.RealmCallback
Warning:com.sun.mail.imap.protocol.IMAPSaslAuthenticator$1: can't find referenced class javax.security.sasl.RealmChoiceCallback
Warning:com.sun.mail.imap.protocol.IMAPSaslAuthenticator$1: can't find referenced class javax.security.auth.callback.NameCallback
Warning:com.sun.mail.imap.protocol.IMAPSaslAuthenticator$1: can't find referenced class javax.security.sasl.RealmCallback
Warning:com.sun.mail.imap.protocol.IMAPSaslAuthenticator$1: can't find referenced class javax.security.sasl.RealmChoiceCallback
Warning:javax.activation.CommandInfo: can't find referenced class java.beans.Beans
Warning:okio.DeflaterSink: can't find referenced class org.codehaus.mojo.animal_sniffer.IgnoreJRERequirement
Warning:okio.Okio: can't find referenced class java.nio.file.Files
Warning:okio.Okio: can't find referenced class java.nio.file.Path
Warning:okio.Okio: can't find referenced class java.nio.file.OpenOption
Warning:okio.Okio: can't find referenced class java.nio.file.Path
Warning:okio.Okio: can't find referenced class java.nio.file.OpenOption
Warning:okio.Okio: can't find referenced class org.codehaus.mojo.animal_sniffer.IgnoreJRERequirement
Warning:okio.Okio: can't find referenced class java.nio.file.Path
Warning:okio.Okio: can't find referenced class java.nio.file.OpenOption
Warning:okio.Okio: can't find referenced class java.nio.file.Path
Warning:okio.Okio: can't find referenced class java.nio.file.OpenOption
Warning:okio.Okio: can't find referenced class org.codehaus.mojo.animal_sniffer.IgnoreJRERequirement
Warning:org.apache.harmony.awt.ContextStorage: can't find referenced class java.awt.Toolkit
Warning:org.apache.harmony.awt.ContextStorage: can't find referenced class java.awt.GraphicsEnvironment
Warning:org.apache.harmony.awt.ContextStorage: can't find referenced class java.awt.Toolkit
Warning:org.apache.harmony.awt.ContextStorage: can't find referenced class java.awt.GraphicsEnvironment
Warning:org.apache.harmony.awt.datatransfer.DTK: can't find referenced class java.awt.datatransfer.DataFlavor
Warning:org.apache.harmony.awt.datatransfer.DTK: can't find referenced class java.awt.datatransfer.SystemFlavorMap
Warning:org.apache.harmony.awt.datatransfer.DTK: can't find referenced class java.awt.dnd.DropTargetContext
Warning:org.apache.harmony.awt.datatransfer.DTK: can't find referenced class java.awt.dnd.peer.DropTargetContextPeer
Warning:org.apache.harmony.awt.datatransfer.DTK: can't find referenced class java.awt.dnd.DragGestureEvent
Warning:org.apache.harmony.awt.datatransfer.DTK: can't find referenced class java.awt.dnd.peer.DragSourceContextPeer
Warning:org.apache.harmony.awt.datatransfer.DTK: can't find referenced class java.awt.datatransfer.SystemFlavorMap
Warning:org.apache.harmony.awt.datatransfer.DTK: can't find referenced class java.awt.datatransfer.DataFlavor
Warning:org.apache.harmony.awt.datatransfer.DTK: can't find referenced class java.awt.datatransfer.SystemFlavorMap
Warning:org.apache.harmony.awt.datatransfer.DTK: can't find referenced class java.awt.datatransfer.DataFlavor
Warning:org.apache.harmony.awt.datatransfer.DTK: can't find referenced class java.awt.datatransfer.SystemFlavorMap
Warning:org.apache.harmony.awt.datatransfer.DataProvider: can't find referenced class java.awt.datatransfer.DataFlavor
Warning:org.apache.harmony.awt.datatransfer.DataProxy: can't find referenced class java.awt.datatransfer.Transferable
Warning:org.apache.harmony.awt.datatransfer.DataProxy: can't find referenced class java.awt.datatransfer.SystemFlavorMap
Warning:org.apache.harmony.awt.datatransfer.DataProxy: can't find referenced class java.awt.datatransfer.UnsupportedFlavorException
Warning:org.apache.harmony.awt.datatransfer.DataProxy: can't find referenced class java.awt.datatransfer.DataFlavor
Warning:org.apache.harmony.awt.datatransfer.DataProxy: can't find referenced class java.awt.Image
Warning:org.apache.harmony.awt.datatransfer.DataProxy: can't find referenced class java.awt.datatransfer.DataFlavor
Warning:org.apache.harmony.awt.datatransfer.DataProxy: can't find referenced class java.awt.datatransfer.UnsupportedFlavorException
Warning:org.apache.harmony.awt.datatransfer.DataProxy: can't find referenced class java.awt.datatransfer.SystemFlavorMap
Warning:org.apache.harmony.awt.datatransfer.DataProxy: can't find referenced class java.awt.datatransfer.DataFlavor
Warning:org.apache.harmony.awt.datatransfer.DataProxy: can't find referenced class java.awt.datatransfer.SystemFlavorMap
Warning:org.apache.harmony.awt.datatransfer.DataProxy: can't find referenced class java.awt.datatransfer.DataFlavor
Warning:org.apache.harmony.awt.datatransfer.DataProxy: can't find referenced class java.awt.image.DirectColorModel
Warning:org.apache.harmony.awt.datatransfer.DataProxy: can't find referenced class java.awt.image.DataBufferInt
Warning:org.apache.harmony.awt.datatransfer.DataProxy: can't find referenced class java.awt.image.Raster
Warning:org.apache.harmony.awt.datatransfer.DataProxy: can't find referenced class java.awt.image.ComponentColorModel
Warning:org.apache.harmony.awt.datatransfer.DataProxy: can't find referenced class java.awt.color.ColorSpace
Warning:org.apache.harmony.awt.datatransfer.DataProxy: can't find referenced class java.awt.image.ComponentColorModel
Warning:org.apache.harmony.awt.datatransfer.DataProxy: can't find referenced class java.awt.image.DataBufferByte
Warning:org.apache.harmony.awt.datatransfer.DataProxy: can't find referenced class java.awt.image.Raster
Warning:org.apache.harmony.awt.datatransfer.DataProxy: can't find referenced class java.awt.image.DataBufferUShort
Warning:org.apache.harmony.awt.datatransfer.DataProxy: can't find referenced class java.awt.image.BufferedImage
Warning:org.apache.harmony.awt.datatransfer.DataProxy: can't find referenced class java.awt.datatransfer.SystemFlavorMap
Warning:org.apache.harmony.awt.datatransfer.DataProxy: can't find referenced class java.awt.datatransfer.DataFlavor
Warning:org.apache.harmony.awt.datatransfer.DataProxy: can't find referenced class java.awt.Image
Warning:org.apache.harmony.awt.datatransfer.DataProxy: can't find referenced class java.awt.datatransfer.DataFlavor
Warning:org.apache.harmony.awt.datatransfer.DataProxy: can't find referenced class java.awt.image.BufferedImage
Warning:org.apache.harmony.awt.datatransfer.DataProxy: can't find referenced class java.awt.image.ColorModel
Warning:org.apache.harmony.awt.datatransfer.DataProxy: can't find referenced class java.awt.image.WritableRaster
Warning:org.apache.harmony.awt.datatransfer.DataSnapshot: can't find referenced class java.awt.datatransfer.SystemFlavorMap
Warning:org.apache.harmony.awt.datatransfer.DataSnapshot: can't find referenced class java.awt.datatransfer.DataFlavor
Warning:org.apache.harmony.awt.datatransfer.DataSource: can't find referenced class java.awt.datatransfer.DataFlavor
Warning:org.apache.harmony.awt.datatransfer.DataSource: can't find referenced class java.awt.datatransfer.Transferable
Warning:org.apache.harmony.awt.datatransfer.DataSource: can't find referenced class java.awt.datatransfer.SystemFlavorMap
Warning:org.apache.harmony.awt.datatransfer.DataSource: can't find referenced class java.awt.datatransfer.DataFlavor
Warning:org.apache.harmony.awt.datatransfer.DataSource: can't find referenced class java.awt.datatransfer.Transferable
Warning:org.apache.harmony.awt.datatransfer.DataSource: can't find referenced class java.awt.datatransfer.DataFlavor
Warning:org.apache.harmony.awt.datatransfer.DataSource: can't find referenced class java.awt.Image
Warning:org.apache.harmony.awt.datatransfer.DataSource: can't find referenced class java.awt.datatransfer.DataFlavor
Warning:org.apache.harmony.awt.datatransfer.DataSource: can't find referenced class java.awt.image.BufferedImage
Warning:org.apache.harmony.awt.datatransfer.DataSource: can't find referenced class java.awt.Image
Warning:org.apache.harmony.awt.datatransfer.DataSource: can't find referenced class java.awt.image.BufferedImage
Warning:org.apache.harmony.awt.datatransfer.DataSource: can't find referenced class java.awt.Graphics
Warning:org.apache.harmony.awt.datatransfer.DataSource: can't find referenced class java.awt.image.BufferedImage
Warning:org.apache.harmony.awt.datatransfer.DataSource: can't find referenced class java.awt.image.WritableRaster
Warning:org.apache.harmony.awt.datatransfer.DataSource: can't find referenced class java.awt.image.DataBufferInt
Warning:org.apache.harmony.awt.datatransfer.DataSource: can't find referenced class java.awt.datatransfer.DataFlavor
Warning:org.apache.harmony.awt.datatransfer.DataSource: can't find referenced class java.awt.datatransfer.Transferable
Warning:org.apache.harmony.awt.datatransfer.DataSource: can't find referenced class java.awt.datatransfer.DataFlavor
Warning:org.apache.harmony.awt.datatransfer.DataSource: can't find referenced class java.awt.datatransfer.SystemFlavorMap
Warning:org.apache.harmony.awt.datatransfer.DataSource: can't find referenced class java.awt.datatransfer.DataFlavor
Warning:org.apache.harmony.awt.datatransfer.DataSource: can't find referenced class java.awt.Image
Warning:org.apache.harmony.awt.datatransfer.DataSource: can't find referenced class java.awt.image.BufferedImage
Warning:org.apache.harmony.awt.datatransfer.DataSource: can't find referenced class java.awt.Graphics
Warning:org.apache.harmony.awt.datatransfer.DataSource: can't find referenced class java.awt.image.BufferedImage
Warning:org.apache.harmony.awt.datatransfer.DataSource: can't find referenced class java.awt.image.DataBufferInt
Warning:org.apache.harmony.awt.datatransfer.DataSource: can't find referenced class java.awt.datatransfer.DataFlavor
Warning:org.apache.harmony.awt.datatransfer.DragSourceEventProxy: can't find referenced class java.awt.Point
Warning:org.apache.harmony.awt.datatransfer.DragSourceEventProxy: can't find referenced class java.awt.dnd.DragSourceContext
Warning:org.apache.harmony.awt.datatransfer.DragSourceEventProxy: can't find referenced class java.awt.dnd.DragSourceEvent
Warning:org.apache.harmony.awt.datatransfer.DragSourceEventProxy: can't find referenced class java.awt.dnd.DragSourceContext
Warning:org.apache.harmony.awt.datatransfer.DragSourceEventProxy: can't find referenced class java.awt.dnd.DragSourceDropEvent
Warning:org.apache.harmony.awt.datatransfer.DragSourceEventProxy: can't find referenced class java.awt.dnd.DragSourceDragEvent
Warning:org.apache.harmony.awt.datatransfer.DragSourceEventProxy: can't find referenced class java.awt.dnd.DragSourceContext
Warning:org.apache.harmony.awt.datatransfer.DragSourceEventProxy: can't find referenced class java.awt.Point
Warning:org.apache.harmony.awt.datatransfer.DragSourceEventProxy: can't find referenced class java.awt.dnd.DragSourceContext
Warning:org.apache.harmony.awt.datatransfer.DragSourceEventProxy: can't find referenced class java.awt.Point
Warning:org.apache.harmony.awt.datatransfer.DragSourceEventProxy: can't find referenced class java.awt.dnd.DragSourceContext
Warning:org.apache.harmony.awt.datatransfer.DragSourceEventProxy: can't find referenced class java.awt.Point
Warning:org.apache.harmony.awt.datatransfer.DragSourceEventProxy: can't find referenced class java.awt.dnd.DragSourceContext
Warning:org.apache.harmony.awt.datatransfer.DragSourceEventProxy: can't find referenced class java.awt.Point
Warning:org.apache.harmony.awt.datatransfer.DragSourceEventProxy: can't find referenced class java.awt.dnd.DragSourceDragEvent
Warning:org.apache.harmony.awt.datatransfer.FlavorsComparator: can't find referenced class java.awt.datatransfer.DataFlavor
Warning:org.apache.harmony.awt.datatransfer.NativeClipboard: can't find referenced class java.awt.datatransfer.Clipboard
Warning:org.apache.harmony.awt.datatransfer.TextFlavor: can't find referenced class java.awt.datatransfer.DataFlavor
Warning:org.apache.harmony.awt.datatransfer.TextFlavor: can't find referenced class java.awt.datatransfer.SystemFlavorMap
Warning:org.apache.harmony.awt.datatransfer.TextFlavor: can't find referenced class java.awt.datatransfer.DataFlavor
Warning:org.apache.harmony.awt.datatransfer.TextFlavor: can't find referenced class java.awt.datatransfer.SystemFlavorMap
Warning:org.apache.harmony.awt.datatransfer.TextFlavor: can't find referenced class java.awt.datatransfer.DataFlavor
Warning:there were 261 unresolved references to classes or interfaces.
Warning:Exception while processing task java.io.IOException: Please correct the above warnings first.
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesAndResourcesWithProguardForRelease'.
> Job failed, see logs for details
Information:BUILD FAILED
Information:Total time: 3.68 secs
Information:1 error
Information:122 warnings
Information:See complete output in console
```

I tried some ProGuard rules to avoid that problem, it successful in building the app. But when I install the app on my device and open it, it shows no UI and then the device freez and then it forced to close from the system.

Can anyone help me with the right rules for the ProGuard in my situation.

Comment: have you specified the classes and packages which should not be obfuscated in your `proguard.txt` file?

Comment: try In file option click Invalidate caches/Restart of studio. also clean project and rebuild this may help.

Comment: @SripadRaj This is not related to obfuscation, read my answer to know why this happens.

Comment: @Omi Still the same problem. I think the solution is to get the right rules for ProGuard to avoid the warnings and at the same time do not make the app forced to close with empty UI. I am unlucky to get the right rules, so I posted here...

Comment: @SripadRaj The problem is how I know what are the classes that I should keep..! Are these classes are those shown in that warning message?!

Comment: @Androider follow Eugene's answer. :)

Comment: Referenced classes are not actually in your project or dependencies so you can't keep them. You just have to tell proguard you know about it. And the libraries need to be designed to work without missing classes or you work with portions of libraries that don't require these classes.

Answer (score 1):

Referenced classes are not actually in your project or dependencies so you can't keep them.

Some libraries are built with a dependency on new platform code or another library but are designed to work without it as well. If you don't include these dependencies in your project you get warnings. All of this is completely fine and expected, you just have to tell proguard you know about this.

For example you use Okio which depends on java.nio but that's only available in plain Java and Android O. Okio is designed to work without java.nio but you have to tell proguard that you're OK with this. So you add this to your proguard rules:

```
# Okio
-keep class sun.misc.Unsafe { *; }
-dontwarn java.nio.file.*
-dontwarn org.codehaus.mojo.animal_sniffer.IgnoreJRERequirement
-dontwarn okio.**
```

You'll find more rules for other libraries here: https://github.com/krschultz/android-proguard-snippets/tree/master/libraries

If you don't find rules for a library but are confident the library will work and just need to shut proguard up `-dontwarn` is your friend. E.g.

```
-dontwarn org.apache.harmony.awt.datatransfer.DataProxy
-dontwarn org.apache.harmony.awt.datatransfer.NativeClipboard
```

or if you want to shut up everything from a package

```
-dontwarn org.apache.harmony.awt.**
```